# Unity3d - Loading array of objects by using parent folder name in asset bundle?

Tags: sprite, unity-game-engine, assetbundle

I have created an asset bundle which has sprites in folder hierarchy. What I want is that I get array of these sprites by using the parent folder name. Is this possible?

I can get single sprite using

```
 AssetBundle.LoadAsset<Sprite>("spriteName.png");
```

but I want array of sprites using the parent folder name. How can I do this?

Thank you

Comment: try  this http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.LoadAssetWithSubAssets.html

Comment: I tried it but its something else. I think its used for extracting individual sprites form a sprite sheet using asset bundle.

Comment: Btw i dont understand when you say "asset bundle which has sprites in folder hierarchy", So you made sub folders and you want all sprites in a array , if thats the case why put them in folders in the first place ?

Comment: Use this http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.LoadAllAssets.html then cast them into sprites.

Comment: Let me explain. For example, I have folders named "Monsters" and "Players". Monsters folder contains sprites of monsters and Players folder contains sprites of Players. I built an asset bundle with this hierarchy. So, what I want is that if I call Monsters folder and it returns me an array of sprites of monster and same for Players.

Comment: LoadAllAssets loads all the assets without the folder hierarchy. It will load all the sprites and folder hierarchy will be gone. For example, I have 100 sprites in my asset bundle. But I only want 10 sprites of monsters. Calling LoadAllAssets will load 100 sprites instead of 10.

Comment: so put them in different folders??

Comment: While building they are already put in different folders. But when asset bundle is made, this hierarchy vanishes and we can only reference the objects with their names.